# Dereferencing a pointer multiple times vs creating temp variable

Tags: c, pointers

I had a while loop looking like:

```
while (str[i] != *p)
    ++i;
```

and a friend popped over and mentioned that it would be faster to do:

```
char c = *p;
while (str[i] != c)
    ++i;
```

I guess the question is:

if I dereference a pointer multiple times, at what point does it become faster to create a temp variable.

Comment: The compiler probably treats the two the same if the code is optimized.

Comment: These are micro optimizations. Do not waste time in these stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `*p` is not `volatile` qualified, the compiler is allowed to load the `*p` only once and do what your friend is proposing.

So in "normal" code you should prefer readability and maintainability and let the compiler do its job. If in doubt, you can look at the assembler that the compiler produces, usually with option `-S`.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a little bit faster.  It won't be a whole lot faster.  If you really care, you'll have to measure it.

Much more important than microoptimization is clarity and accuracy.  Depending on the usage of the pointer `p` in the program, it may be extremely obvious that it's what points to the character being compared to, meaning that `str[i] != *p` is a good, clear test, and that introducing the new variable `c` would make the code that much harder to follow.  Or, if it's not so obvious that `*p` is the character being compared to, then introducing a new variable -- and maybe calling it `character_being_compared_to` -- would make the code clearer (and also perhaps that little bit faster).

But there's also the question of whether `p`'s value ever changes, meaning that the character it points to becomes different.  If `p`'s value can ever change, then copying `*p` into `c` means you keep comparing against the old value, which might be a bug.

Each variable you add to your program costs something: it costs you (and everyone who ever maintains your code) mental effort to keep track of.  So variables have to "carry their weight": they have to be *for* something.  There's a certain benefit in *not* introducing new variables, especially if the value of the new variable has to be kept in sync with the value of other variables.  The benefit gained by adding the new variable (in this case, the alleged speedup) has to be greater than the cost of adding it.

Your friend is doing what a lot of inexperienced programmers do: imagining that the computer is some frail, inefficient, wheezing rattletrap of a machine, and that it's our job to make things easier for it.  But that's exactly backwards: computers are actually insanely fast, and it's *their* job to make *our* jobs easier for *us*.  So, in general, first write code that's clear and that works, and if it has performance issues then maybe worry about how to speed it up, but don't be too worried about trivial little issues like this making it harder on the poor old computer.

Answer (score 0):

If the compiler generates the code as it is, without any optimization.

*p will generate code that dereference a memory location

While char c = *p would create a temporary variable which it may
a) put in a stack and dereference it
b) put in a register and use it for the whole loop

Generally, a happens when the loop is more complex and b happens when generating simple loops that requires not much registers.

So depending on where p is pointing to, whether there is an optimization, whether the loop is simple enough and many more factors, you may have different results.

But to answer your question, unless you are well aware of what the compiler will generate it is generally better to create that char.

This will serve well when *p is a function call like GetSize() instead, but that is another topic altogether.